# Generate Reference number

Tags: html, google-sheets, userform

I want to create a random reference number for my user form in google sheets, this is coded via google app script. This is the script that I used.

```
function generateRandomReferenceNumbers(numberOfNumbers) {
      var randomReferenceNumbers = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++) {
        randomReferenceNumbers.push(generateRandomReferenceNumber());
      }


  return randomReferenceNumbers;
    }

    function addNewRow(agency,census) {

      const currentDate = new Date();
      generateRandomReferenceNumbers();

      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
      ws.appendRow([generateRandomReferenceNumbers,currentDate,agency,census]);
    }

    function run(){

    addNewRow("Agency",100)

    }
```

Here's the google sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zuw8V8Lhdml_VzjfCd5S58ROcy2B9kmGrnH6EBDDtFs/edit#gid=0

I already tried different functions but I can't seem to get it right. How can I get this to work?

Comment: The Google sheet link shows "Access denied", you need to edit the permission(s)

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.random function

```
const min = 1;
const max = 10;
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

console.log(randomNumber);
```

Or if you want to generate a uniqueId use third party library such as uuidjs

```
<!-- HTML5 -->
<script type="module">
import { UUID } from "https://unpkg.com/uuidjs@^5";
const uuid = UUID.generate();
</script>
```